# Filter an in-tooltip visual using a Lookup type filter

Tags: tooltip, tableau-api

Sample Tableau Workbook with Superstore data: https://filebin.net/jkph5ccuzmzr3y21

I have a chart that shows both a weekly view, and a cumulative view, and a parameter swaps between the two.

In the attached example, we have a parameter that has two possible values, "Weekly" and "Cumulative".

`[Sales (Weekly/Cumulative)]` looks like this:

```
IF [Weekly/Cumulative] = "Weekly" THEN
  SUM([Sales])
ELSEIF  [Weekly/Cumulative] = "Cumulative" THEN
  RUNNING_SUM(SUM(Sales))
END
```

I've added a text table to show the Week detail as a Viz in the tooltip, and this works great when we select "Weekly". But for "Cumulative" the tooltip still shows a total for a single week, rather than the running total number. This is because when we switch to the Cumulative view, we're using a Table Calculation, and Table Calculations only calculate based on what's in the view. When you filter by Week = 38 (for example), the detail table only shows week 38, and so there's no running total.

In a normal viz, you would overcome this by using a filter like `LOOKUP(MIN([Week]), 0)` to filter without messing up the table calculation. Is there a way to do that for the "in tooltip" visual?